# Ubuntu 21.04 can not join to domain with user name.surname

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory

During the installation Ubuntu 21.04 in menu "Configure Active Directory" can not use Domain administrator username like `name.surname`:

> Error: May only contain lower-case letters, digits, hyphens, and underscores.

Is it possible to get around this limitation?
zmy domain uses a point (`.`) for dividing the name and surname.

Comment: I'm really hoping someone answers this. I'd like to know too.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for programming questions specifically.  This may be a better fit for https://askubuntu.com/, though do check their [on topic page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) first.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could figure out was just to change my username to have a dot in it right after installing Ubuntu. I followed these instructions here: [Ask Ubuntu: How do I change my username?](https://askubuntu.com/a/317008/327339).